# Crashes python.exe: ucrtbase.DLL

Tags: python, tensorflow, jupyter-notebook

When I try to run tensorflow Python crashes with the following message:

```
Problem signature:
  Problem Event Name:     BEX64
  Application Name: python.exe
  Application Version:    3.5.3150.1013
  Application Timestamp:  58ae5709
  Fault Module Name:      ucrtbase.DLL
  Fault Module Version:   10.0.10240.16384
  Fault Module Timestamp: 559f3851
  Exception Offset: 0000000000065a4e
  Exception Code:   c0000409
  Exception Data:   0000000000000007
  OS Version: 6.3.9600.2.0.0.400.8
  Locale ID:  1033
  Additional Information 1:     83e2
  Additional Information 2:     83e2a3a910bd8aa1d2961e6f372a944e
  Additional Information 3:     7d79
  Additional Information 4:     7d7900ee94188f7fcafaf4c671dcabeb
```

It seams to be something related to the vcc runtime.

Any help will be welcome.

Comment: it's possible you C runtime needs to be updated. check out this microsoft support page. https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2999226/update-for-universal-c-runtime-in-windows

Answer (score 0):

I was having [same error](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45090994/5330223) while trying to run visual studio 15 code using visual studio 12 specific libraries from OpenCV.

So, if you are trying to build a c++ program named `python.exe` check the dependent libraries or if you are trying to run an existing `python.exe` program, check whether necessary visual studio [redistributables](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=48145) are installed as [mark jay](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5156102/mark-jay) said in the comment.